# Passwordless Login

Tags: bash, unix, expect

**Problem statement**

I want to access a server without asking me the password (will be mentioned in the script) and run a command on that server.

**My Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sudo su - <server_name>
expect "[sudo] password for chronicles:"
set Password "xxxxxxx"
send "$Password\r"
#set timeout 300
send "whoami\r"
send "ls -ltr\r"
expect eof
```

**Output**

```
invalid command name "sudo"
    while executing
```

**Restrictions**

- I dont have access rights to change env variables or modify
  .bash_profile / .bashrc.
- su server_name command not allowed

Comment: Is `sudo` in your `PATH`? Try using the full path to your `sudo` executable. You can find this with `which sudo` in your shell.

Comment: @Tyilo -> which sudo gives --- /usr/bin/sudo ....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

David is right that generally this is a **bad** idea.  There are *occasionally* good reasons for doing it, or doing something similar (e.g. automatically logging into serial consoles for lights-out management), but you haven't provided any indication as to why it makes sense for you to do it this way.

Caveats aside, the `invalid command name` is not coming from the `spawn` line but from the `[sudo]` in the `expect` line.  Expect is based on `tcl`, which [treats `[]` square parentheses as special characters indicating command substitution](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M10).  Additionally, the value passed to `expect` is a *glob* pattern not a fixed string, and `[]` square parentheses are also special characters in globs.  So the answer you are looking for is to quote those characters *twice*:

```
    expect "\\\[sudo\\\] password for chronicles:"
```

Also note that after sending the password you should probably include another `expect` line to wait for the root shell prompt.

Comment: The error is not coming .... but its asking my password .. I need to again type my password....Plz help !!

Answer (score 2):

The secure way to access a server without prompting for a password is through keyed logins over SSH. **Don't ever give your password in plain text.**

If you simply Google, you will find many articles explaining how to do this. [SSH login without password](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) is a perfectly fine explanation.

Comment: Yep I agree..we should never give password in plain text. But as I was using "expect"...so I had to....I am following the link which you gave .... Lets c

Comment: But why are you using expect?

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is interpreted as "command quotes" ("command" as in "Tool Command  Language", which is what `Tcl` is short for) in `Tcl`.

`{}` is the strongest quote in `Tcl`, you can use it to prevent any interpretation:

```
expect {[sudo] password for chronicles:}
```

of course you could also just omit `[sudo]`:

```
expect "password for chronicles:"
```